# Import CSV file as a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

How do I read the following [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file into a Pandas [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)?

```
Date,"price","factor_1","factor_2"
2012-06-11,1600.20,1.255,1.548
2012-06-12,1610.02,1.258,1.554
2012-06-13,1618.07,1.249,1.552
2012-06-14,1624.40,1.253,1.556
2012-06-15,1626.15,1.258,1.552
2012-06-16,1626.15,1.263,1.558
2012-06-17,1626.15,1.264,1.572
```

Answer (score 223, accepted):

[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to the rescue:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df)
```

This outputs a pandas [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe):

```
        Date    price  factor_1  factor_2
0  2012-06-11  1600.20     1.255     1.548
1  2012-06-12  1610.02     1.258     1.554
2  2012-06-13  1618.07     1.249     1.552
3  2012-06-14  1624.40     1.253     1.556
4  2012-06-15  1626.15     1.258     1.552
5  2012-06-16  1626.15     1.263     1.558
6  2012-06-17  1626.15     1.264     1.572
```

Answer (score 33):

To read a CSV file as a pandas DataFrame, you'll need to use **[`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)**, which has `sep=','` as the default.

But this isn't where the story ends; data exists in many different formats and is stored in different ways so you will often need to pass additional parameters to `read_csv` to ensure your data is read in properly.

Here's a table listing common scenarios encountered with CSV files along with the appropriate argument you will need to use. You will usually need all or some combination of the arguments below to read in *your* data.

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ pandas Implementation                                 │ Argument              │ Description                                        │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ pd.read_csv(..., sep=';')                             │ sep/delimiter         │ Read CSV with different separator¹                 │
│ pd.read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True)               │ delim_whitespace      │ Read CSV with tab/whitespace separator             │
│ pd.read_csv(..., encoding='latin-1')                  │ encoding              │ Fix UnicodeDecodeError while reading²              │
│ pd.read_csv(..., header=False, names=['x', 'y', 'z']) │ header and names      │ Read CSV without headers³                          │
│ pd.read_csv(..., index_col=[0])                       │ index_col             │ Specify which column to set as the index⁴          │
│ pd.read_csv(..., usecols=['x', 'y'])                  │ usecols               │ Read subset of columns                             │
│ pd.read_csv(..., thousands='.', decimal=',')          │ thousands and decimal │ Numeric data is in European format (eg., 1.234,56) │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

> **Footnotes**
>
> 1. By default, `read_csv` uses a C parser engine for performance. The C parser can only handle single character separators. If your CSV has
>    a multi-character separator, you will need to modify your code to use
>    the `'python'` engine. You can also pass regular expressions:
>
>    ```
>     df = pd.read_csv(..., sep=r'\s*\|\s*', engine='python')
>    ```
> 2. `UnicodeDecodeError` occurs when the data was stored in one encoding format but read in a different, incompatible one. Most common
>    encoding schemes are `'utf-8'` and `'latin-1'`, your data is likely to
>    fit into one of these.
> 3. `header=False` specifies that the first row in the CSV is a data row rather than a header row, and the `names=[...]` allows you to
>    specify a list of column names to assign to the DataFrame when it is
>    created.
> 4. "Unnamed: 0" occurs when a DataFrame with an un-named index is saved to CSV and then re-read after. Instead of having to fix the
>    issue while reading, you can also fix the issue when writing by using
>
>    ```
>     df.to_csv(..., index=False)
>    ```

There are other arguments I've not mentioned here, but these are the ones you'll encounter most frequently.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an alternative to pandas library using Python's built-in [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
with open('foo.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    column = {h:[] for h in headers}
    for row in reader:
        for h, v in zip(headers, row):
            column[h].append(v)
    pprint(column)    # Pretty printer
```

will print

```
{'Date': ['2012-06-11',
          '2012-06-12',
          '2012-06-13',
          '2012-06-14',
          '2012-06-15',
          '2012-06-16',
          '2012-06-17'],
 'factor_1': ['1.255', '1.258', '1.249', '1.253', '1.258', '1.263', '1.264'],
 'factor_2': ['1.548', '1.554', '1.552', '1.556', '1.552', '1.558', '1.572'],
 'price': ['1600.20',
           '1610.02',
           '1618.07',
           '1624.40',
           '1626.15',
           '1626.15',
           '1626.15']}
```

Comment: The [first revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14365542/1) specifically asks how to create a DataFrame, as done in R. This does not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score -2):

Note quite as clean, but:

```
import csv

with open("value.txt", "r") as f:
    csv_reader = reader(f)
    num = '  '
    for row in csv_reader:
        print num, '\t'.join(row)
        if num == '  ':  
            num=0
        num=num+1
```

Not as compact, but it does the job:

```
   Date price   factor_1    factor_2
1 2012-06-11    1600.20 1.255   1.548
2 2012-06-12    1610.02 1.258   1.554
3 2012-06-13    1618.07 1.249   1.552
4 2012-06-14    1624.40 1.253   1.556
5 2012-06-15    1626.15 1.258   1.552
6 2012-06-16    1626.15 1.263   1.558
7 2012-06-17    1626.15 1.264   1.572
```

Comment: The [first revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14365542/1) specifically asks how to create a DataFrame, as done in R. This does not answer the question that was asked.