# How to specify custom parser in Pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to open a `file.csv` in Pandas. For that, I can use `pd.read_csv('file.csv')`.

The problem is, the file is not properly formatted:

```
a b   c
1 2   5
3 4   6
```

The first delimiter is 1 space and the second delimiter is 3 spaces.

I couldn't find a way on pandas documentation on how to do that.

I can pre process the file beforehand, transform it to a `StringIO` and open with pandas, but it seems hackish to me.

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = text.replace('   ', ' ')
    text = StringIO(text)
    df = pd.read_csv(text)
```

How can I do that with pandas directly?

Comment: Use `delim_whitespace=True` instead. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231664/4909087)

Comment: What's the benefit over `sep='\s+'`?

Comment: regex argument to `sep` invokes the python parser which is slower. I'm not sure if `delim_whitespace` does the same but it is definitely more idiomatic.

Comment: Indeed more idiomatic. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\s+')`?

Comment: Dammit, I need to learn regex. Many thanks