# Unicode Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, decode

I have this kind of Error when I want to read csv in Jupyter Notebook in Pandas: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 37: invalid continuation byte` what should I do?, use encoding argument ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231664/4909087) under the "Fix UnicodeDecodeError while reading" scenario. TLDR; it was saved using a different encoding that isn't compatible with utf-8.

Comment: it still does not work

Comment: "it still does not work" what exactly did you try?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("datasets/myfile.csv", encoding='latin-1')

Comment: Here's a relevant thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python