# How to read a csv and aggregate data by groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

We have a csv file and written below code to do a group by and get the max value and create an output file. But while reading final output file using data-frame read_csv , it is showing as empty..

```
Input file: 

Manoj,2020-01-01 01:00:00
Manoj,2020-02-01 01:00:00
Manoj,2020-03-01 01:00:00
Rajesh,2020-01-01 01:00:00
Rajesh,2020-05-01 01:00:00
Suresh,2020-04-01 01:00:00

Final output file:

Manoj,2020-03-01 01:00:00
Rajesh,2020-05-01 01:00:00
Suresh,2020-04-01 01:00:00
```

and then when i am trying to read above final output file using df.read_Csv it shows dataframe empty.

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
z=open('outfile.csv','w')
fin=[]
k=open('j.csv','r')
for m in k:
    d=m.split(',')[0]
    if d not in fin:
        fin.append(d.strip())

for p in fin:
    gg=[]
    g=re.compile(r'{0}'.format(p))
    y=open('j.csv','r')
    for b in y:
        if re.search(g,b):
            gg.append(b)
    z.write(gg[-1].strip())
    z.write('\n')

df = pd.read_csv("outfile.csv", delimiter=',', names=['Col1','Col2'], header=0)

print(df)

final output: Empty DataFrame , Index: []
```

Is there anything i missed , please any one suggest...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import CSV file as a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365542/import-csv-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's not necessary to use the `for-loop` to process the file. The data aggregation is more easily completed in `pandas`.
- Your `csv` is shown without headers, so read the file in with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), `header=None`, and use `parse_dates` to correctly format the datetime column.

  - The column with datetimes, is shown at column index 1, therefore `parse_dates=[1]`
  - This assumes the data begins on row 0 in the file and has no headers, as shown in the OP.
- Create headers for the columns
- As per a comment, the `date` component of `'datetime'` can be accessed with the [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor).
- [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `name` and aggregate `.max()`

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file j.csv
df = pd.read_csv('j.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[1])

# add headers
df.columns = ['name', 'datetime']

# select only the date component of datetime
df.datetime = df.datetime.dt.date

# display(df)
     name    datetime
0   Manoj  2020-01-01
1   Manoj  2020-02-01
2   Manoj  2020-03-01
3  Rajesh  2020-01-01
4  Rajesh  2020-05-01
5  Suresh  2020-04-01

# groupby
dfg = df.groupby('name')['datetime'].max().reset_index()

# display(dfg)
     name    datetime
0   Manoj  2020-03-01
1  Rajesh  2020-05-01
2  Suresh  2020-04-01

# save the file. If the headers aren't wanted, use `header=False`
dfg.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This answers my question.. Can you pls suggest me if possible. How to send an HTML table in body of the email ?

Comment: I tried and now how can i send that html file in body of an email ?

Comment: @Ravi i'm not sure, that would be a different question. I tried cutting and pasting into a gmail email, but the html doesn't render.

Answer (score 1):

Create dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(zip(
    ['Manoj','Manoj','Manoj','Rajesh','Rajesh','Suresh'],
    ['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-01-01','2020-05-01','2020-04-01'],
    ['01:00:00','01:00:00','01:00:00','01:00:00','01:00:00','01:00:00']),
    columns=['name','date','time'])
```

Convert date and time from string to date and time object

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True).dt.date
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

Take groupby

```
out=df.groupby(by=['name','time']).max().reset_index()
```

You can save and load it again

```
out.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
df1=pd.read_csv('out.csv')
```

result

```
    name      time        date
0   Manoj  01:00:00  2020-03-01
1  Rajesh  01:00:00  2020-05-01
2  Suresh  01:00:00  2020-04-01
```

Sorry, I created two separate columns for date and time, but I hope you can understand it