# How to use pandas or equivalent python library to parse a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file data.csv with below file content(| delimited)

```
A|B|X|Y|Z
S|T|U|V|W|X
```

I want to parse this file to print the data in below format(1st two columns constant and third column split by | and generate new row

```
A|B|X
A|B|Y
A|B|Z
S|T|U
S|T|V
S|T|W
S|T|X
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import CSV file as a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365542/import-csv-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `read_csv` and `melt`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='|', header=None).melt([0,1])
```

Output:

print(df.melt([0,1]))

```
         0           1  variable         value
0  1338980  2528742011         2  B00HFPOXM4:0
1  1338981  2528742012         2  B00HFPOXCY:0
2  1338980  2528742011         3  B00HFPOX9C:0
3  1338981  2528742012         3  B00HFPOX9W:0
4  1338980  2528742011         4  B00NPZ7WNU:0
5  1338981  2528742012         4  B00HFPOVCG:0
6  1338980  2528742011         5  B00HFPOXCO:0
7  1338981  2528742012         5  B00KGBX5DC:0
```