# Reading Data Troubleshooting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble reading data.  I am using  Mac and have saved files on my desktop with the following names and can see them in the jupyter folder but cannot open them when trying with the following code.  Can anyone advise ?

```
df_students = pd.read_excel(students.xlsx)
df_students
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-14c48be800d6> in <module>
----> 1 df_students = pd.read_excel(students.xlsx)
      2 df_students

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'xlsx'
```

```
df_census = pd.read_csv(census.csv)
df_census
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-fe5b1bb04ec7> in <module>
----> 1 df_census = pd.read_csv(census.csv)
      2 df_census

NameError: name 'census' is not defined
```

Comment: You should pass filenames as string, i.e. within quotes like `df_students = pd.read_excel('students.xlsx')` to read functions.

Comment: Please read more about pd.read_csv [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import CSV file as a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365542/import-csv-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)