# Sorting by column in a CSV and writing to a new CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, file

My code:

```
import csv
import operator


first_csv_file = open('/Users/jawadmrahman/Downloads/account-cleanup-3 array/example.csv', 'r+')
csv_sort = csv.reader(first_csv_file, delimiter=',')
sort = sorted(csv_sort, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
sorted_csv_file = open('new_sorted2.csv', 'w+', newline='')
write = csv.writer(sorted_csv_file)
for eachline in sort:
    print (eachline)
    write.writerows(eachline)
```

I have an example csv file:
[image]

I want to sort by the first column and get the results in this fashion:
1,9
2,17,
3,4
7,10
With the code posted above, this is how I am getting it now:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is `,` supposed to represent a decimal point in this context?

Comment: `pandas` package is the most comprehensive and well supported package for manipulating tabular data such as CSVs. Read, sort, and save should be about 3 lines of code in Pandas. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787698/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-from-one-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365542/import-csv-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `eachline` is itself a list and thus `write.writerows(eachline)` is producing two rows for every `eachline`. Try `write.writerow(eachline)`. While you are at it, I encourage you to look at what the `with` keyword used with `open()` does for you. It will clean up your code substantially.

Comment: Please do not include images of data. Please edit your question and include your input CSV and desired output CSV _as text_.

Comment: @BenGrossmann no.

Comment: @DavidParks, can't use Pandas, this code will go in Lambda. Pandas is way too big for Lambda, disables the debugging for some reason.

Comment: @JonSG, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JonSG pointed out in the comments to your original post, you're calling `writerows()` (plural) on a single row, `eachline`.

Change that last line to `write.writerow(eachline)` and you'll be good.

#### Looking at the problem in depth

`writerows()` expects "a list of a list of values".  The outer list contains the rows, the inner list for each row is effectively the cell (column for that row):

```py
sort = [
  ['1', '9'],
  ['2', '17'],
  ['3', '4'],
  ['7', '10'],
]

writer.writerows(sort)
```

will produce the sorted CSV with two columns and four rows that you expect (and your print statement shows).

When you call `writerows()` with a single row:

```py
for eachline in sort:
    writer.writerows(eachline)
```

you get some really weird output:

- it interprets `eachline` at the outer list containing a number of rows, which means...
- it interprets each item in `eachline` as a row having individual columns...
- and each item in `eachline` is a Python *sequence*, string, so `writerows()` iterates over each character in your string, treating each character as its own column...

  `['1','9']` is seen as two single-column rows, `['1']` and `['9']`:

  ```
  1
  9
  ```

  `['2', '17']` is seen as the single-column row `['2']` and the double-column row `['1', '7']`:

  ```
  2
  1,7
  ```

Comment: Ah I understand. This works, thank you!