# Why is my csv file not printing after I import it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
import pandas as pd 
tbl1 = pd.import_csv('sample_prices.csv') 
tbl1.print()
```

and still not receiving anything? It does not even come up with an error.

Comment: Does this resolve your issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365542/import-csv-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `import_csv()` is not an actual pandas function, as far as I can see.  Please post your real code.

Comment: `import` has [special meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) in Python, so please don't use it to mean something else like  using data produced by another application.

Answer (score 0):

The code might be written this way.

```
import pandas as pd
tbl1 = pd.read_csv('sample_prices.csv')
print(tbl1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: That solved it. Cheers man.

Answer (score 0):

It should be writed like this

```
import pandas as pd

tbl1 = pd.read_csv('sample_prices.csv')
print(tbl1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.import_csv` doesn't exist. You probably meant to use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead.

```
import pandas as pd 
tbl1 = pd.read_csv('sample_prices.csv') 
tbl1.print()
```

That said, I'm not sure why it wouldn't raise an error...

If you have a custom function called `import_csv`, you'll want to call it like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
tbl1 = import_csv('sample_prices.csv') 
tbl1.print()
```

...without the `pd.` prefix.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thank you very much.