# Python - Compare two files and write changed rows and new rows to a new file

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python (Pandas being acceptable) I need to compare **file2** to **file1** and output to **file3** the rows from **file2** that are either:

1. Present in **file1** but have some changed values
2. Not present in **file1**

**file1**

```
ID,Format,Output,FontSize,isDefault
1,LP,LETTER,14,False
2,LP,LETTER,16,False
3,LP,LETTER,18,True
4,LP,LETTER,20,False
5,LP,LETTER,22,False
```

**file2**

```
ID,Format,Output,FontSize,isDefault
2,LP,LETTER,16,False
3,AU,LETTER,18,False
4,BR,LETTER,20,False
5,LP,LETTER,22,False
6,LP,LEDGER,24,False
7,LP,LEDGER,36,False
```

**file3**

```
ID,Format,Output,FontSize,isDefault
3,AU,LETTER,18,False
4,BR,LETTER,20,False
6,LP,LEDGER,24,False
7,LP,LEDGER,36,False
```

In this example the **ID** column is unique.

Comment: please describe your logic of `compare`. if it is very general file comparing, then there are lot of existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are CSVs, and that the IDs are simply the row numbers, you could get a `csv.reader()` to get lists of the rows from the two files. Then you loop over them to see if the same row exists in both files; if not, you add them to a new list:

```
new_list = []
number_of_rows = min(len(list_from_file1), len(list_from_file2))
for i in range(number_of_rows):
    if list_from_file1[i] != list_from_file2[i]:
        new_list.append(list_from_file2[i])
```

That will copy all rows that exist in both files but with different content into new_list. You can then also copy all remaining rows from the longer file into new_list too, and write new_list into file3 with csv.writer.

Comment: The IDs are not the row numbers. ID 2 from file2 needs to be compared to ID 2 from file1 and if there is a change it needs to be written to file3. If there is a ID present in file2 but not in file 1 then it also needs to be written to file3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading csv files, try this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

#Instead of below 2 lines of code, read data from files using the link at the end of code, below.
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'LP','LETTER',14,False],[2,'LP','LETTER',16,False]], columns =['ID','Format','Output','FontSize','isDefault'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2,'LP','LETTER',16,False],[3,'AU','LETTER',18,False]], columns =['ID','Format','Output','FontSize','isDefault'])

result = []

for index, row_df2 in df2.iterrows():
    if row_df2['ID'] in df1.ID.to_list():
        row_df1 = df1[df1.ID == row_df2['ID']].iloc[0] 
        if np.array_equal(row_df2.values,row_df1.values):
            result.append(row_df2.to_list()   )
    else:
        result.append(row_df2.to_list()  )

#Write to CSV file
with open('file3.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
     wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     wr.writerow(['ID','Format','Output','FontSize','isDefault'])
     for val in result:
        wr.writerow(val)
```

[Import CSV file as a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365542/import-csv-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe)