# How to categorize a data given into category and subcategory using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

How to get the result showing in picture 2 from the data shown in picture 1 using python pandas.?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category': ['Fruit','Vegetable','Vegetable','Fruit','Vegetable','Vegetable','Fruit','Vegetable','Fruit','Vegetable'],
    'SubCategories': ['Apple','Brinjal','Brinjal','Apple','Carrot','Potato','Apple','Carrot','Banana','Brinjal'],
    'Count': [2,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1],
})

df.set_index(['Category','SubCategories']).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
```

Note that you can use `df = pd.read_csv()` if you are reading an external csv file. For information on this, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365542/import-csv-file-as-a-pandas-dataframe) question.