# Using regex in python to delete (or replace) parentheses and items inside them

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I have a csv file that looks like the following:

```
Halley Bailey - 1998 
Hayley Orrantia (1994-) American actress, singer, and songwriter 
Ken Watanabe (actor) 
etc...
```

I’d like to remove the items in the parentheses, as well as the commas in some of the names that have commas, so that the dataframe looks like this:

```
Halley Bailey
Hayley Orrantia
Ken Watanabe
```

I attempted using the following code, which succeeds in removing the dates after the name, but not the parentheses or things after commmas, how could I expand it so it can replace all these items?

```
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df['actors']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following `'(^[^\(|^\-]+)'` returning all matches before a `-` or `(`:

```
df['Full Name'] = df['Description'].str.extract('(^[^\(|^\-]+)')
```

Returning:

```
                                         Description        Full Name
0                               Halley Bailey - 1998    Halley Bailey 
1  Hayley Orrantia (1994-) American actress, sing...  Hayley Orrantia 
2                               Ken Watanabe (actor)     Ken Watanabe
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: KeyError: 'id' from the following code. The only column in the dataframe with the actors names is id

`df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', encoding="latin-1")`

`df['id'] = df['id'].astype('|S')`


`df.head()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the csv content is in stored in the column `csv` of the dataframe `df`, and that `df` looks like the following (if one doesn't know how to read a CSV into a Pandas Dataframe, see first Notes below)

```
                                                 csv
0                               Halley Bailey - 1998
1  Hayley Orrantia (1994-) American actress, sing...
2                               Ken Watanabe (actor)
```

If one wants to create a new column named `actors`, considering that an actor full name is only composed of `2` words, the following will do the work

```
df['actors'] = df['csv'].str.split(' ').str[:2].str.join(' ')

[Out]:

                                                 csv           actors
0                               Halley Bailey - 1998    Halley Bailey
1  Hayley Orrantia (1994-) American actress, sing...  Hayley Orrantia
2                               Ken Watanabe (actor)     Ken Watanabe
```

If, on another hand, one doesn't want to create a new column, one can do the following

```
df['csv'] = df['csv'].str.split(' ').str[:2].str.join(' ')

[Out]:

               csv
0    Halley Bailey
1  Hayley Orrantia
2     Ken Watanabe
```

---

**Notes:**

- If one doesn't know how to read a `.CSV` file as a `Pandas` `DataFrame`, this should be relevant - [Import CSV file as a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14365542/7109869) (particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231664/7109869))
- Depending on the dataframe, one might have to adjust the column names.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why you use both 'actors' and 'csv', my dataframe only has one column ('id'). Should I just use 'id' both times?

Comment: @NicoO `actors` is to create a new column named `actors`. As I do not know the column of your dataframe `df`, I assumed it was `csv`. If the column is named `id`, and in that column you have the content similar to the `csv` column in the Output of my answer, then it is a matter of changing in the script from `csv` to `id`.

Comment: This works, thanks Goncalo, I still get some of the names with  a - (e.g. Ernest Hogen -).  Do you know what I can add to the regex to fix this?

Comment: Hard to come up with a regex that solves all the possible use cases without having access to the whole data. My recommendation is for you to ask a different question indicating specifically the cases that the solution(s) is/are not solving.